# How do I exclude weekends (SQL)

Tags: date-math

I have different Year, Month and Day columns,
And I wish to exclude weekends.

How can I do so?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Database Administrators! Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using, e.g. [sql-server], [postgresql], [oracle], [db2], ...

Comment: What is a weekend for you? That word has different meaning in different areas of the world.

Answer (score 2):

The exact answer will depend on which SQL database product you're using, because they all support different functions for date manipulation. For example, [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/05cb9/6) is a demo for this SQL Server query:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, day)
  FROM table1
  WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, day))
          NOT IN (1, 7) -- Sunday, Saturday
```

and [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iKjGSujwxdaNgh72yhiEfk/0) is one for MySQL:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(year, 1),
                         INTERVAL (month)-1 MONTH),
                INTERVAL (day)-1 DAY)
  FROM table1
  WHERE WEEKDAY(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(year, 1),
                         INTERVAL (month)-1 MONTH),
                INTERVAL (day)-1 DAY))
          NOT IN (5, 6) -- Saturday, Sunday
```